# Recursively reduce an array of consecutive duplicate numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

The base challenge was to reduce an array of numbers (featuring consecutive duplicates) by adding together neighbouring clones:

```
const sumClones = (numbers) => {
 if (Array.isArray(numbers)) {
  return numbers.reduce((acc, elem, i, arr) => {
   if (elem !== arr[i - 1]) acc.push(elem);
   else acc[acc.length - 1] += elem;
   return acc;
  }, []);
 } 
};
```

sumClones([1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]) => [2,2,4,2,3]

Now, I'm trying to write another function reduceClones that recursively runs sumClones so that the final output contains no consecutive duplicates

```
const reduceClones = (numbers) => {
  let result = sumClones(numbers);
  while (result[0] === result[1]) {
    result = sumClones(result);
  }
  return result;
};
```

reduceClones([1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]) => [8,2,3]

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The `while (result[0] === result[1])` termination condition doesn't appear to be correct. I recommend monitoring whether length of result changes, instead.

Answer (score 0):

- Always use pure functions.
- always work with first element of the input array.
- while it has duplicates: collect them
- call `self` until input array is consumed
- return `res`

```js
function reduceConsecutiveClones(nums, res) {
  if(!nums.length) { return res || []; }
  if(!res) {
    res = [];
    nums = nums.slice();
  }
  
  let sum = first = nums.shift();
  
  while(first === nums[0]) {
    sum += nums.shift();
  }
  
  return reduceConsecutiveClones(
    nums, 
    res.concat(sum)
  );
}

function reduceClones(nums, res = reduceConsecutiveClones(nums)) {
  
  return res.toString() === nums.toString()
    ? res
    : reduceClones(res)
  ;
}


console.log(
  reduceConsecutiveClones([1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]),
  reduceClones([1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

By taking use of array destructuring in a Haskellesque way you may do as follows;

```js
function sumNeigboringDupes([x1,x2,...xs]){
  
  function add2Head(a,[b,...rest]){
    return [a+b].concat(...rest);
  }
  
  return xs.length ? x1 === x2 ? add2Head(x1,sumNeigboringDupes([x2,...xs]))
                               : [x1].concat(sumNeigboringDupes([x2,...xs]))
                   : x1 === x2 ? [x1 + x2]
                               : [x1, x2 || []];
}

var arr = [1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,4,4,1];
console.log(JSON.stringify(sumNeigboringDupes(arr)));
```

**Hint:** `[x1,x2,...xs]` for the argument of `sumNeigboringDupes` function just takes an array and assign `x1` to the first item, `x2` to the second item and `xs` is an array which is assigned to the rest of the array. The array destructuring at `add2Head` function's arguments also works in a similar fashion.